# Vue.js 2 - How to $emit event from one application/instance Vue to an other?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use webpack with Single File Component.

I have 1 instance of Vue in my menu header to show a Cart Shopping dropdown :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './AppShoppingCart.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#shoppingCartApp',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: {App}
});
```

I have an other Vue instance in the same page (the catalog with products) :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './AppCatalog.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#catalogApp',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: {App}
});
```

I want to $emit an event from one instance to the other :
when Catalog change, I want to call a function in ShoppingCart.

I test [eventHub](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced) :

```
import Vue from 'vue';

var eventHub = new Vue();
export default eventHub;
```

So I import event on each instance :

```
import eventHub from './events/eventHub';
```

In Catalog :

```
eventHub.$emit( "actproductslist-changed" );
```

In ShoppingCart :

```
eventHub.$on('actproductslist-changed', function(){ alert('AppShoppingCart') } );
```

But this won't works. It only works if the $on and $emit are in the same instance of Vue.

I think webpack create 2 modules and I can't share variables between my 2 instances.

### Any one have an idea to have global variable with multiple instance with webpack ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This setup works, where `main.js` is your entry point.

**bus.js**

```
import Vue from "vue"

const bus = new Vue();
export default bus;
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import App2 from './App2.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app2",
  render: h => h(App2)
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <button @click="sendMessage">Send Message</button>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from "vue"
  import bus from "./bus"

  export default {
    methods:{
      sendMessage(){
        bus.$emit("testing")
      }
    }    
  }
</script>
```

**App2.vue**

```
<template></template>

<script>
  import Vue from "vue"
  import bus from "./bus"

  export default {
    mounted(){
        bus.$on("testing", ()=> alert("message received"));
    }
  }
</script>
```

### Post comment edit

To communicate across entry points, you can expose the `bus` Vue on the window.

**webpack.config.js**

```
  entry: {
    "main": './src/main.js', 
    "main2": './src/main2.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
```

**bus.js**

```
import Vue from "vue"

window.bus = new Vue();
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**main2.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App2 from './App2.vue'
import bus from "./bus"

new Vue({
  el:"#app2",
  render: h => h(App2)
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <button @click="sendMessage">Send Message</button>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from "vue"

  export default {
    methods:{
      sendMessage(){
        if (bus)
          bus.$emit("testing")
      }
    }    
  }
</script>
```

**App2.vue**

```
<template></template>

<script>
  import Vue from "vue"

  export default {
    mounted(){
        bus.$on("testing", ()=> alert("message received"));
    }
  }
</script>
```

Note here that since `bus` is only imported in `main2.js`, you need to guard the use of it in `App.vue` for those cases where it might not exist (because it is only imported in `main2.js`).

Comment: You are right. But in my case I have 2 main.js because one is use on every page (cart shopping dropdown) and the other is only for the catalog page. So I have 2 entry/output files. It seems strange to have in shoppingCart.js an if( #catalogApp is present in html ) => instantiate the catalogVue too. What do you think ? I have an javascript solution (with addEventListener on a div #shoppingCartEventHub) but I prefer a Vue solution.

Comment: @vuefan Yeah I'm not sure what would allow you to communicate across entry points. I'll have to play around with that when I have time.

Comment: @vuefan Updated. Exposing the `bus` on the window allows you to communicate between them.